# How to access the Items of a User Control

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms

I have a C# Form that prints multiple instances of a **User Control**.  Let's say that the form prints 5 instances of the User Control (Please see the link attached). How can I store/save the data inputted in all User Controls? Thanks

Here is the screenshot of the C# Form: 
[image]

Comment: One solution is to expose your data through properties in your user control.

Comment: how exactly do I do that? I am very new to C#

Comment: create properties for each control in UserCotntrol. then you can access value of each user cotrol item. ie. `(MyUserControl)pnlLayout.Controls[0].DG = "1";`

Comment: How do I do that @Nimesh? Is it the get-set method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a property like this for each item in user control.

```
public string DG
{
    get
    {
        return txtDG.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        txtDG.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the control value by using following line in your form.
supposed you have created a usercontrol **MyControl** and you have placed some object of this control in FlowLayoutPenal (pnlFLP).

To get value from control

```
string DG = ((MyControl)pnlFLP.Controls[0]).DG;
```

To set value in control

```
((MyControl)pnlFLP.Controls[0]).DG = "1";
```

Comment: what is pnlFLP? It says in C#: "pnFLP does not exist in the current context"

Comment: it is just a name of FlowLayoutPanel control object you have taken in your form. I have mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: Hi Nimesh, your code worked perfectly. I am marking your answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to store the User Controls when you instantiate them in a List or something.

You could have a class like this:

```
class SomeUC : UserControl
{
    public SomeUC()
    {
    }

    // A public method.
    public string GetData()
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Where `textBox1` is the Name of a `TextBox` in your `SomeUC`

And then inside your main or something.

```
// Instantiate a List that will hold your UserControls, this has to be outside all methods
List<SomeUC> list = new List<SomeUC>();


// And now when you want to build your UCs
// Instantiate your UserControl
SomeUC uc1 = new SomeUC();
// Store your UserControl in a List or something (Can't help you with that)
list.Add(uc1);
```

Add as much as you want.
A `List` is not the only way you can do that, but since you don't know how many UserControls you're going to build beforehand, it makes since to use a `List`.
And then you can access them from the list by their index.

```
SomeUC uc1 = list[0];
string data = uc1.GetData();
```

This is an example of accessing one control (the `TextBox`) in your `SomeUC`. For other classes (such as the `ComboBox`) the interaction is different. Meaning you won't have a `Text` property in the `ComboBox`. You'll have to figure out things like that on youself. A little research is what it takes. You can always come back if you couldn't find a solution for something.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. However, do you know how to Implement it using User Contorls? My C# Project already uses User Controls

Comment: @intMain just call out the things you think don't make sense. It's worth mentioning again that it's better that you work around the basics of UI interaction until you're comfortable enough before implementing `UserControl`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for accessing user control in the page

```
Dim txtName As TextBox = TryCast(UserControlName.FindControl("txtName"), TextBox)
```

Comment: Hi..what did you need extactly,Need to access the controls inside the User Controls Right?